# sqlalchemy bind table to multiple engines

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two different mysql databases with the same schema. 
In short I want to use sqlalchemy to read from one database and insert the data into the other one.

Here is my code so far

```
   Base = declarative_base()  
   class Test(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'test'
       ID = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
       Name = Column(String,nullable=True)
       Updated = Column(Integer)

   sourceEngine  = create_engine(sourceDBString)
   destEngine = create_engine(destDBString)
   Base.metadata.bind = sourceEngine

   SourceSession = sessionmaker()
   SourceSession.bind = sourceEngine
   DestSession = sessionmaker(destEngine)

   source_session = SourceSession()
   destSession = DestSession()
   notupdated = source_session.query(Test).filter_by(Updated=0)

   for row in notupdated:
      row.Updated=1
   destSession.add_all(notupdated)
   destSession.commit() 
   source_session.commit()
   destSession.close()
   source_session.close()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Test at 0x7f7e1a83ce50>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')
```

It seems to be that I can only bind the object Test to one engine at a time, is there any  way I can set both engines to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `make_transient` to transfer an object from one session to another.  You may also want to clear the `obj.id` column by setting it to `None`.

This SO question should help you further.
[How to use make_transient() to duplicate an SQLAlchemy mapped object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287042/how-to-use-make-transient-to-duplicate-an-sqlalchemy-mapped-object)