# Reusing detached ORM objects across SQLAlchemy sessions during testing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand what SQL-Alchemy does to orm objects. They must have some state attached to them I'm not groking. In the below example, `test_one` will succeed, but `test_two` will fail because the Employee object will not be added to the session in `test_two`. Somewhere in sqla internals it sees that the object is already added to a session and deleted from a session even though the session is closed in the module scope so `test_two` should have a brand new session. My workaround was to wrap the defaults in a function and return new instances of the orm objects each time. Still curious what is happening?

Some things I've tried:
Call `expunge_all`, `expire_all`, `expunge` the object etc when I close the session.
On the second call to `add_all` in `test_two`, the objects are added the sessions `identity_map` but on `commit()` it's never added to the db. Hence the second assert fails.

This is a Flask app using Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy 1.4

defaults.py

```
from myapp.models import Employee
    EMPLOYEES = [
            Employee(employee_id=8, given_name='first', family_name='last', email='test@example.com')
    ]
```

conftest.py
`mysql_proc` is a fixture provided by pytest-mysql

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app(mysql_proc):
    url = f'mysql+mysqldb://root:@127.0.0.1:3307'
    # create the test database before we connect using TestingConfig
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=False, poolclass=NullPool)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb')
        conn.execute('USE mydb')

    url = f'mysql+mysqldb://root:@127.0.0.1:3307/mydb'
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=True, poolclass=NullPool)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        db.metadata.create_all(bind=conn)

    # this will use Flask-SQLAlchemy's session from now on
    app = create_app(TestingConfig())
    yield app

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_engine(mysql_proc):
    url = f'mysql+mysqldb://root:@127.0.0.1:3307/mydb'
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=False, poolclass=NullPool)
    yield engine
    engine.dispose()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_session_maker(db_engine):
    return scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=db_engine))

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def core_session(app, db_session_maker):
    session = db_session_maker()
    yield session
    session.rollback()
    session.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def employees_fixture(core_session):
    core_session.add_all(EMPLOYEES)
    core_session.commit()
    yield core_session
    core_session.execute(delete(Employee))
    core_session.commit()
```

test_one.py

```
import pytest
from myapp.models import Employee

def test_one(core_session, employees_fixture):
    assert core_session.query(Employee).count() == 1
```

test_two.py

```
import pytest
from myapp.models import Employee

def test_two(core_session, employees_fixture):
    assert core_session.query(Employee).count() == 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to call `make_transient` in addition to calling `expunge`.  If you print the `__dict__` of the objects you can see there is still state in the objects.

```
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7fb3957f2a40>, 'employee_id': 8, 'given_name': 'first', 'family_name': 'last', 'email': 'test@example.com'}
```

Although I think your original solution of a function returning fresh objects is probably a better idea.  The employees should just be a fixture anyways.

[sqlalchemy.orm.make_transient](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.make_transient)

I think this will probably be error prone but I was able to make this work with this code:

```py
import os
import sys
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
    NullPool,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, text, delete
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased, relationship, joinedload, scoped_session, sessionmaker, make_transient
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Env:
    db_owner: str
    db_name: str
    db_password: str

env = Env(**{'db_' + k: os.environ.get('DB_' + k.upper()) for k in ('owner', 'password', 'name')})


url = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{env.db_owner}:{env.db_password}@/{env.db_name}"


Base = declarative_base()


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'
    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    given_name= Column(String)
    family_name=Column(String)
    email=Column(String)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def EmployeeClass():
    return Employee

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def EMPLOYEES():
    return [Employee(employee_id=8, given_name='first', family_name='last', email='test@example.com')]


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app():
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=True, poolclass=NullPool)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)



@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_engine(app):
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=False, poolclass=NullPool)
    yield engine
    engine.dispose()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_session_maker(db_engine, EMPLOYEES):
    yield scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=db_engine))


def expunge(session, EMPLOYEES):
    print(f"Expunging employees {len(EMPLOYEES)}")
    for emp in EMPLOYEES:
        print (emp.__dict__)
        if emp in session:
            session.expunge(emp)
            make_transient(emp)

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def core_session(app, db_session_maker, EMPLOYEES):
    session = db_session_maker()
    yield session
    session.rollback()
    session.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def employees_fixture(core_session, EMPLOYEES):
    core_session.add_all(EMPLOYEES)
    core_session.flush()
    core_session.commit()
    yield core_session
    core_session.execute(delete(Employee))
    core_session.commit()
    expunge(core_session, EMPLOYEES)
```

```py
import pytest

def test_one(EmployeeClass, core_session, employees_fixture):
    assert core_session.query(EmployeeClass).count() == 1
```

```py
import pytest

def test_two(EmployeeClass, core_session, employees_fixture):
    assert core_session.query(EmployeeClass).count() == 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the answer because it seems this is the proper way and put me on the proper path. I still could not get my tests to work right, as calling make_transient on the Employee objects sets all the attributes to None. There is mention of this in the docs but I don't know why it's doing that. Also may need to set [_oid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287042/how-to-use-make-transient-to-duplicate-an-sqlalchemy-mapped-object) to None although not sure if that is still valid in 2.0 (I see this var begins with _)

Comment: @mikew I didn't test it with flask but tried to create a reasonable parallel setup.  I'm not sure if when I run the expunge/make_transient call matters so I included the test code.

Comment: If I remove the `make_transient` call it fails as you described.